# How to Install two different chaincodes in two different channels

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I created two channels named:

- first
- second

I want to install two different chaincodes in the two channels how can I achieve this????

Answer (score 1):

Installation of one chaincode code into specific channel not very different from doing the same, e.g. installing two chaincodes into two separate channels, please consider read [official tutorial](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/chaincode4noah.html). In fact the chaincode installation is out of channel context, installation is the process of literally moving chaincode bytes into peer file system.

Basically the operation is fairly simple you just need to specify different channel names and different chaincodes, something like this:

```
peer chaincode install -o localhost:7050 -n chaincode1 -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincodes/chaincode1
```

and then the second one:

```
peer chaincode install -o localhost:7050 -n chaincode2 -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincodes/chaincode2
```

above will move both chaincodes bytes into peer's file system. Next you just need to instantiate chaincodes in context of right channel:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o localhost:7050 -n chaincode1 -v 1.0 -C first -c '{"Args":[]}'
```

and to instantiate second chaincode for second channel:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o localhost:7050 -n chaincode2 -v 1.0 -C second -c '{"Args":[]}'
```

You can find some more explanatory examples in [fabric-samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples) repository.

Comment: can we have multiple chaincodes in just one channel @artemBarger

Comment: I am able to create and invoke two chaincode on one channel but while running the commands I am getting error "Error endorsing invoke: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: Invalid Document Smart Contract function name.)"  any suggestions for this?